# An example of a non-rectifiable curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

How can I solve this problem?

> Let the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the equation $\alpha(t)=(t,g(t)), t\in [0,1]$, where $$g(t)=\left\{ \begin{aligned} t \cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2t}\right), \quad t\not=0 \\ 0, \quad t=0\end{aligned}\right.$$
> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let the partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ given by $$P=\left\{ 0, \frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1},\ldots, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1\right\},$$ prove the length $\ell_n$ of the polygonal inscribed satisfies $$\ell_n>\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$and and deduce that the curve $\alpha$ is not rectifiable.

**My approach:**  I know for example that if I prove that arc length of $\alpha$ is infinite, so I can say that $\alpha$ is not rectifiable, so I need to calculate $I_{n}$.

I know that the arc-length of a curve $\alpha$ is $$s(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \|\dot{\alpha}(t)\| \, dt$$
so I need to prove that $s(t)\to \infty \implies \alpha$ is not rectifiable.

I know how calculate $\dot{\alpha}(t)$, but how can I choose $t_0$ and $t$?

---

**Questions:**
*Now, How can I prove the first part? It's to say, how can I prove that $\ell_n>\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$? and how can I relate that result to the fact that alpha is not rectifiable?*

Comment: I have the impression that you are not aware of where the integral formula for arclength comes from. I guess that's the connection you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb N$, you have

$$\begin{aligned}\left\Vert \alpha(\frac{1}{n+1}) - \alpha(\frac{1}{n}) \right\Vert &=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2}\right)}{n+1}-\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)}{n}\right)^2}\\
&\ge \frac{1}{n+1}
\end{aligned}$$

as one of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2}\right) , \cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$ vanishes while the absolute value of the other one is equal to one. This enables to get the required inequality

$$l_{n}>\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}.$$

As the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) of  a curve is greater than a polygonal path approximating it and that the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$diverges, you get that $\alpha$ is not rectifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea. In the euclidean plane, the shortest path between two point is the straight line. Let $P = \{ 0,\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n-1},\ldots, \frac{1}{2},1\} = \{ x_0,x_1,\ldots x_{2n}\}$. Consider the points $M_k$ on the graph of $g$ defined by $M_k = (x_k,g(x_k))$. Because the straight line is the shortest path in the plane, one has $\mathrm{length}(g|_{[x_k,x_{k+1}]}) \geqslant \mathrm{length}([M_k,M_{k+1}])$. As $P$ is a partition of $[0,1]$, $\mathrm{length}(g|_{[0,1]})=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\mathrm{length}(g|_{[M_k,M_{k+1}]})$.

So now you have the inequality:
\begin{align}
\forall n \geqslant 1,~ \mathrm{length}(g) \geqslant A_n
\end{align}
where $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \mathrm{length}\left([M_k,M_{k+1}]\right)$. Try to bound from below these last terms and you are done.

Comment: You wrote that it's BECAUSE the straight line is the shortest path, but in this argument one should use the fact that the arc length is DEFINED AS the supremum of lengths of polygonal paths given in this way by a partition. The supremum of a set is at least as large a number than are any of the numbers that are members of the set. The logical structure of an argument should be attentive to definitions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  You are right, we can use this definition. OP seems to use the arc-length definition which is not - apparently - this one. Also, I find your comment a bit aggressive. Using caps locks does not make an argument more powerful.

Comment: By arc-legth definition, I meant arc-length definition of $C^1$ parametrized curves, with $\mathrm{length}(\gamma|_I) = \int_I \|\gamma'\|$.

Comment: I was directing the reader's attention to certain things.