# What it means for a curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ to be rectifiable?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

There is a theorem in Stein's book 'Real analysis' that gives a sufficient and necessary condition for a curve  $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$  to be rectifiable, which is as follows:

> Theorem 3.1(page 116):A curve parametrized by $(x(t), y(t)),\, a ≤ t ≤ b$, is rectifiable if and only if both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are of bounded variation (you can check the definition of 'bounded variation function' [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation)).

The proof is straightforward, but I was struggling to gain a little intuition about this theorem, for example letting $x(t) = t$ means the graph of function shouldn't oscillate so much on a small enough domain.

I have 2 questions:

1. oscilation is the only problem that can happen when dealing with the case  $x(t) = t$ ?
2. can $x(t)$ be of unbounded variation and curve still be graph of a function?

Actually answering the second question answers the first question too. Thanks

Comment: Is "rectifiable" also defined for $x(t)$? Or do you mean "of bounded variation" in 2?

Comment: You are right, sorry. edited.

Comment: What does it mean that a curve is the graph of a function? If it means, as I a think, that $x(t) = t$, then 2. does not make sense.

Comment: It doesn't mean necessarily that $x(t) = t$ for example consider $x(t) = t^{2} , y(t) = t^{2}$.

Comment: In what sense is $\gamma(t) =( t^2, t^3)$ a graph? Do you mean that the image $\gamma([a,b])$ is the graph of some map $\delta : [c,d] \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3901764.